# How to write a tag wiki

Tags: discussion, faq-proposed

There needs to be a guideline of what's the recommended way on Web Applications to write a tag wiki. Feel free to use this post as a starting discussion and eventual future FAQ for WebApps tag wiki edits. Here is an excerpt from an old post about [writing good tag wikis](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/redesigned-tags-page/)

> 1. The excerpt is the elevator pitch for the tag. You only have ~500
>      plain text characters for the excerpt, so don’t feel obligated to
>      cover everything in it! Save that for the 30,000+ character Markdown
>      tag wiki. The excerpt should define the shared quality of questions
>      containing this tag — boiled down to a few short sentences
> 2. Avoid generically defining the concept behind a tag, unless it is
>      highly specialized. The “email” tag, for example, does not need to
>      explain what email is. I think we can safely assume most internet
>      users know what email is; there’s no value in a boilerplate
>      explanation of email to anyone.
> 3. Concentrate on what a tag means to your community. For “email” on
>      Server Fault, mention the server aspects of email including POP3,
>      SMTP, IMAP, and server software. For “email” on Super User, mention
>      desktop email clients and explicitly exclude webmail, as that would
>      be more appropriate for webapps.stackexchange.com.
> 4. Provide basic guidance on when to use the tag. In other words, what
>      kinds of questions should have this tag? Tags only exist as ways of
>      organizing questions, so if we don’t provide proper guidance on
>      which questions need this tag, they won’t get tagged at all,
>      rendering the tag excerpt moot. Think of it as a sales pitch: in a
>      room full of tags screaming “pick me!”, what would convince a
>      question asker to select your tag?
> 5. Some tags are common knowledge. Most tags require a bit of
>      explanation in the excerpt, even if it’s only 3 or 4 words. But if
>      the tag is common knowledge — that is, if you walked up to any
>      random person on the street and said the tag word to them, and they
>      would know what you were talking about — then don’t bother
>      explaining the tag at all. Stick to usage of the tag within your
>      community in the excerpt.