# Better tag guidance for tags that attract development questions

Tags: discussion, tags, clean-up

In spite of our best efforts, we still get daily questions about web application development.

Obviously, people don't read. Part of the problem may be that some of the tags that a web app developer would expect to use exist here and, in general, have very poor usage guidance. (See also: [Tag Excerpt (guidance) improvement project](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4028/tag-excerpt-guidance-improvement-project))

[javascript](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript), at least, has some immediate clue that a developer is in the wrong place and, since they're adding the tag to the question, is pretty much in their face.

> Questions about JavaScript are generally OFF-TOPIC here. You might be able to find your answer at Stack Overflow.

Others, not so much. For instance, [database](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/database) only has

> System that handles large amounts of data in an organised fashion

There's no guidance there at all. Further, what database question could possibly be on-topic at Web Apps? Most questions are already closed as off-topic (or should be), are about Google Sheets as a database, or are just mis-tagged.

Similar is [html](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/html):

> Markup language used to create the layout of most web pages.

Still, no usage guidance. Unfortunately, there are a few places where using the tag makes seems to make sense: How to get HTML to render in a Google Doc, or in YouTube comments, for instance. But it's also used inappropriately on a bunch of others.

So, my question is multi-layered:

- What other tags, due to their lack of usage guidance, seem to be implicitly signaling that development/programming questions are on-topic?
- Do those tags make sense to even exist here?
- For those that make sense to stay, how can we improve their wiki excerpt?

Some more:

- [java](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/java)
- [mysql](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mysql)

Comment: I've read on other sites about some tags being "meta" tags. The impression I get, probably wrong, is that a meta tag is one that can't be used unless there's some other tag to attach it to. So, ih `html` was a meta tag, then in the good example you gave they would have to select the `google-documents` tag first, then attach the `html` tag for clarification. An improper question about HTML couldn't just use the `html` tag solo. If I understand meta tags correctly, couldn't some of the tags here, such as `html` and `javascript` be made meta tags?

Answer (score 3):

## WIP (Work in progress)

> [javascript](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript), at least, has some immediate clue that a developer is in the wrong place and, since they're adding the tag to the question, is pretty much in their face.

Other tags:

The following lock to be meta-tags

- [api](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/api)
- [integration](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integration)

> - What other tags, due to their lack of usage guidance, seem to be implicitly signaling that development/programming questions are on-topic?

APIS:

- [google-api](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-api),[twitter-api](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/twitter-api),[google-chart-api](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-chart-api)

Languages:

- [html5](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/html5),[css](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/css),

Web applications features/components:

- [user-interface](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/user-interface),[access-control](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/access-control),[accessibility](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/accessibility)

Web App Developers/developers tools:

- [facebook-developers](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-developers),[google-developers-console](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-developers-console)

> - Do those tags make sense to even exist here?

Probably it make sense that those tags exists as the tags might be created by users that are not participating in Web Applications Meta / not really care about the site scope and workings or by the the migration process.

> - For those that make sense to stay, how can we improve their wiki excerpt?

I think that the most important is to include a link to https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic and [faq](/questions/tagged/faq), more specifically to [What kind of questions can I ask here? The detailed version](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/894/88163) and to [Where can I ask a question about one of the phases of the development lifecycle of web applications?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4685/88163).

Also We could request that tag warnings be added to them.

Comment: Hmmm...yeah. APIs probably should be included, although perhaps they could be handled in a separate question.

Comment: @ale: I added more tags.