# Who are our experts in [database]? Do we need this tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-clean-up

A few moments ago, near the top of the Homepage, I found a question having only [database](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/database). It was a question about the syntax of WP_Query object. The question is closed. I agree with that.

I mention the above as the context of why I am posting this now. It looks to me that this tag is one among others that confuse the scope of Web Applications SE, making some people think that questions about Web app development and administration are on-topic when they aren't.

[database](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/database) has 31 questions. 16 of those questions are closed.

Eleven open questions have [google-sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets) and [database](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/database). The other four open questions are from 4 different web apps; they don't look to get any benefit of having [database](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/database).

The all-time top answerers based on the number of answers are top answerers of [google-sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets). Both have three answers (I'm one of them). All other all-time answerers have posted only one answer.

Is there an active expert using [database](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/database) to find questions to answer?

## Related

- [Better tag guidance for tags that attract development questions](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4105/88163)

Comment: Added [tag:featured] 1. The discussion about the research policy has ended 2. It was posted six days ago; it didn't get attention yet. 3. It's one of the tags attraction off-topic question / causing confusion about the site scope.

Comment: I don't think this tag matters either way; the important thing is for each question to be tagged with the name of its webapp (which seems to be mostly true, at least for this set). There are more pressing issues to focus on, both in terms of time and space on the main site home page.

Comment: @Laurel **Some** posts don't get the attention that the OP and others might be looking for from moderators because they have problems that have not been addressed. While some problems might not be evident, the posts having them have already been escalated and are being discussed. If you think that there is a specific issue that is pressing more than others, it might be possible that a different way to approach the issue could help to have a more visible way to share updates / progress. Please excuse me for not giving more details.

Answer (score 0):

The questions having [database](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/database) that were blatantly off-topic were deleted. They were:

- Asking for a software recommendation
- About software development
- Defuncted services

I will continue reviewing the remaining questions, having [database](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/database) from the oldest to the newest.

## Addendum

| Milestone | Date | Remarks |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Tag Wiki Meta SE's feature-requests, [Create a tag homepage/FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1195/), [Tag description](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/38250/) | June 2009 and February: 2010 respectively |  |
| Private Beta Start | June 10, 2010 |  |
| Public Beta Start | July 7, 2010 |  |
| "Info" tab of tags, including a [tag wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1195/create-a-tag-homepage-faq/49723#49723) and a [tag synonym proposal system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57479) implemented. | July 22, 2010 | Source: [Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99024/) to [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/59445/) |
| Site Launch/Graduation as Nothing To Install | September 30, 2010 |  |
| Site Renamed to Web Applications | October 1, 2010 |  |
| Creation of [database](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/database) wiki | November 3, 2011 | The oldest capture on The Wayback Machine of the [What are tags, and how should I use them?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/tagging) is from [2013-11-06 11:26:13](https://web.archive.org/web/20131106112613/https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/tagging) |