# "Require" askers to check the tag excerpt and wiki before posting a question

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

## Suggestion

On Stack Overflow sites (at least on the English and Spanish "versions"), Server Fault and maybe other SE sites too, it's "required"<sup>1</sup> to check the tag excerpts / wiki besides searching and researching but this not happen on Web Applications.

> <sup>1</sup>: This is a soft requirement as it's enforced by the community through up/down votes and closing votes.

Following is a suggestion on how this new requirement could be worded for Web Applications:

> ### How do I ask a good question?
>
> We’d love to help you. To improve your chances of getting an answer,
> here are some tips:

#### Search, look at the tag excerpt and wiki and research

> Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your
> question?

Have you reviewed the specific guidelines for asking questions about the tags you choose?

> Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found
> and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken
> the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious
> answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant
> answer!
>
> #### Be on-topic
>
> Our community is defined by a specific set of topics that you can view
> in the help center; please stick to those topics and avoid asking for
> opinions or open-ended discussion. If your question is about the site
> itself, ask on our meta-discussion site. If you’re looking for a
> different topic, it might be covered on another Stack Exchange site.
>
> #### Be specific
>
> If you ask a vague question, you’ll get a vague answer. But if you
> give us details and context, we can provide a useful answer.
>
> Make it relevant to others
>
> We like to help as many people at a time as we can. Make it clear how
> your question is relevant to more people than just you, and more of us
> will be interested in your question and willing to look into it.
>
> #### Keep an open mind
>
> The answer to your question may not always be the one you wanted, but
> that doesn’t mean it is wrong. A conclusive answer isn’t always
> possible. When in doubt, ask people to cite their sources, or to
> explain how/where they learned something. Even if we don’t agree with
> you, or tell you exactly what you wanted to hear, remember: we’re just
> trying to help.

## How is included "the requirement" about tags on other SE sites

### SO sites

#### From https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

> **Include all relevant tags**
>
> Try to include a tag for the language, library, and specific API your
> question relates to. If you start typing in the tags field, the system
> will suggest tags that match what you've typed - be sure and read the
> descriptions given for them to make sure they're relevant to the
> question you're asking! See also: [What are tags, and how should I use
> them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

#### From https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

At this time it's the official translation of the  https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging

> **Incluye todas las etiquetas relevantes**
>
> Intenta incluid (sic) una etiqueta para el lenguaje, librería y otros
> APIs específicos relacionados a tu pregunta. Si inicias tecleando en
> el campo de etiquetas, el sistema te sugerirá etiquetas que coincidan
> con lo que hayas tecleado - ¡asegúrate y lee la descripción brindadas
> a ellas para cerciorar que ellas son relevantes a la pregunta que
> estás formulando! Mira también: [¿Qué son las etiquetas, y cómo
> debería utilizarlas?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

### Server Fault

#### From https://serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask

> **Include relevant details**
>
> We expect you to be able to distill your problem down to something we can analyze - dumping an entire
> error log and server configuration on the site with "please help!"
> will not be well-received, but specific errors from your logs and the
> section of the configuration file they're referring to will be very
> helpful. Examples of things to include are:
>
> – Your operating system and version ([use the appropriate tags too!](http://serverfault.com/tags))
> – Hardware and Firmware versions, where appropriate
> – The expected and actual results of commands you ran, where appropriate
> – Relevant sections of server logs and configuration files

## Discussions on SE Meta

- On an [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/261452/289691) to [Are the rules of all sites on StackExchange the same?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/252338/289691) has a link to How to ask a good question? but it actually point to a discussion on meta for that site [Asking good Questions for GIS Stack Exchange?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3349)

## Once we agree how on this, how we should proceed

The following question on SE Meta has an answer about this.

[Improved Help Center - site-specific pages and site-specific edits to all pages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/279879/289691)

In summary, we should ask to the Community Manager of this site to make the change

The complete procedure is the following:

> 1. Anyone can suggest a change to the help center on meta.
> 2. The community considers the request and hones it.
> 3. Moderators (or really anyone who knows how to contact us) asks a CM to look at the proposed change.
> 4. Community managers evaluate the change and push it as appropriate.

## Related

- [Troubleshooting guidance](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3799/88163)
- [Tag Excerpt (guidance) improvement project](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4028/88163)
- [How to write a tag wiki](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2542/88163)

Comment: How is it required on other sites?  Do you mean that it's in that section of their help centers that you've cited above?

Comment: @jonsca: I added quotes and made some edits (I changed "other SE sites" by SO sites) and also a note explaning that I'm talking about a "soft requirement".

Answer (score 3):

I believe that this text, without the tag and Tag Wiki provision, is the standard verbiage on all of the sites besides Stack Overflow proper and its sister sites in other languages, as you have pointed out.  As such, this proposal would probably be better addressed on a network-wide level.

I am not aware of any data that substantiate whether the additional provision of "be sure and read the descriptions of them" actually deters off-topic questions on sites bearing that text, though there are a number of reasons why I specifically think adding the text wouldn't work on our site:

- Our Tag Wiki Excerpts are getting a lot better, but many are still of the "Widgettown is a web application that allows you to design your own widgets" ilk, which are not very helpful for new *nor* experienced users to know what is *de facto* on-topic on WebApps
- Many users, even those with the +100 reputation bonus (I can say anecdotally) don't know what we're about here, which means that many haven't take the time to take the Tour, let alone drill down a couple of levels in the Help Center, to where the "How to Ask" advice lives.
- In general terms, even if users know what we're about, they still post development questions here in the hopes that they will be migrated to Stack Overflow to circumvent a ban, even though this is not possible.  A handful of users will simply stick random tags or popular tags onto their questions on purpose

Parenthetically, as is evident from the recent UI changes to Stack Overflow proper, the Help/Tour menu may be short-lived on the remainder of the sites. I'm not sure what is in the cards for exposing users to the help information in the future.

I definitely think this wording change is *reasonable*, if that's something others on the greater network would be amenable to, but I'm not sure how well the proposal would go over on the mother Meta, nor am I truly convinced of how effective it could be.

<sup>[I'm racking my brain as to whether this list of requirements is presented to new (registered) users, but it is definitely not presented to unregistered users, questions from which make up a non-negligible portion of our traffic]</sup>

Comment: I'm gratefully surprise for getting and answer as soon as this one. Thank you. I understand your point and appreciate your suggestions and remarks. I will think and research more before posting something about the list of standard requirements for asking questions on [se] sites specially on their impact on traffic.

Comment: @Rubén You did nothing wrong that bears changing your behavior.  I definitely appreciate all that you do for the site!  I wish there were a silver bullet for bad questions, so definitely keep pondering ideas and don't let a downvote (which more than likely indicated disagreement, I can't speak for the voter) stop you from having reasonable ideas.

Comment: Thanks for your nice words jonsca. By the way, I worked a bit on my research and found that Server Fault's how to ask a good question? also requires to check the tag excerpt and wiki (worded in a different way).

Comment: @Rubén Good to know.  I don't know when the SF help section would have diverged from the SO one, so I don't know if that was something they requested or not.